# Detecting keystrokes

Tags: c

I need to detect a keystroke, without the user pressing enter. What's the most elegant way?

I.e. If the user hits the letter <kbd>Q</kbd>, without pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>, the program does something.

Comment: That's going to be environment-dependent. Is this Windows (keystroke window message)? Linux console (getch might work, or something ncurses)? Linux Gnome/KDE? Java app?

Comment: Its tagged and titled as C, so its either Windows, Linux, or GTK, I think.

Comment: Having tried to achieve this on Mac OS X using a combination of `setvbuf` and `fcntl`, I am now tempted to go read the ncurses source...

Comment: @mathepic, could also be an embedded system, so add uC/OS-II, iTRON, and a host of others to the list ;-)

Comment: It's Linux based, specifically Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In unix/posix, the standard way of doing this is to put the input into non-canonical mode with tcsetattr:

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
    :
struct termios attr;
tcgetattr(0, &attr);
attr.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &attr);
```

See the termios(3) man page for more details (and probably more information than you wanted to know).

Answer (score 3):

In Windows `<conio.h>` provides function `_getch(void)` which can be used to read keystroke without echo-ing them (print them yourself if you want).

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
   int ch;

   puts( "Type '@' to exit : " );
   do
   {
      ch = _getch();
      _putch( ch );
   } while( ch != '@' );

   _putch( '\r' );    // Carriage return
   _putch( '\n' );    // Line feed  
}
```

Comment: No need to `#include <stdio.h>` here, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Theres no good way to do this portably, as far as I know, other than to use a library like `ncurses`, which provides the `getch(void)` function.

Note: It appears `getchar(void)` from `stdio.h` waits until the enter key is pressed then feeds your the characters,s o it won't work.

Comment: Yes, but you can turn off line buffering with raw()/cbreak() which allows the characters to return to the program instantly. See http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/init.html#RAWCBREAK for more information.

Comment: I was talking about `getchar`, not the `ncurses` function `getch`. `getch` will work fine (assuming he reads up on ncurses and raw mode), but `getchar` won't.

Comment: On *nix, stdin is line buffered by default if connected to a tty, and fully buffered if a file or pipe. If it is a tty, then you can do things to its modes, but that generally interacts badly with stdio. ncurses knows how to do this in a somewhat platform independent way.

Comment: @RBerteig: line buffered vs unbuffered vs fully buffered only matter for output in stdio -- it has no effect on input.

Comment: @Chris, we're both right in end effect, but I was wrong in detail. The terminal input is almost certainly line buffered, but by the tty device driver, not stdio, and the buffering would affect read(2) as well as any library built on top of it such as stdio. You do need to politely ask the tty driver to stop buffering in a not very portable way (not even across various *nix variants, let alone Windows) to get single key strokes.

Comment: @RBerteig: termios should work fine on any *nix variant less than 20 years old...