# Is it possible to program your own kbhit() in C?

Tags: c, function, kbhit

I took a class of programming at my university and I am working on some program. I want to know if it is possible to program my own `kbhit()` function. And if it is possible to look, how `kbhit()` is coded.

The purpose is that I need to know how functions I use work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting keystrokes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571212/detecting-keystrokes)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing a KeyPress event in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091191/implementing-a-keypress-event-in-c/21101030#21101030)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no.

C language has no notion of input and output. It relies on a standard library (essentially written in C) that in turn relies on system calls.

Neither the standard library, nor the set of system calls common to Unix-like systems and Windows deal with non blocking system calls, so you have to call system specific ones.

But again, you can call them easily from C language.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

On windows stdio (standard io, like stdin/stdout) is always blocking and thus you need to use os specific system calls to avoid a blocking call like read.

On Linux you can change stdio to be non blocking using fcntl thus avoiding the need for specialized function calls.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

That's how it works:

> It returns a non-zero integer if a key is in the keyboard buffer. It will not wait for a key to be pressed.

Basically you check from *stdin* (assumed to be default input data from keyboard in C language).

There is an implementation [here](http://www.ethernut.de/api/kbhit_8c_source.html) where you can start from.